# The running time of my program in big O time

Tags: math, for-loop, big-o, time-complexity

Can someone help me figure out the running time of this loop? I believe it is O(5nlogn).

```
for(int f = 0; f < Array.length; f++) {
    F = Array[f];
    for(int e = 0; e <= f; e++) {
        E = Array[e];
        for(int d = 0; d <= e; d++) {
            D = Array[d];
            for(int c = 0; c <= d; c++) {
                C = Array[c];
                for(int b = 0; b <= c; b++) {
                    B = Array[b];
                    for(int a = 0; a <= b; a++) {
                        A = Array[a];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you fix your indentation you should be able to answer this yourself.

Comment: Is the running time O(n^5)?

Comment: @lc It's not so simple, unless he guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this is to think about the space you're iterating over.  If you think about it, the loops will iterate over nonnegative integral valuesof (a, b, c, d, e, f) where

> n > f ≥ e ≥ d ≥ c ≥ b ≥ a

Each of these iterations does O(1) work (all loops just assign a variable, which takes O(1) work), so the question is how many possible values there are that satisfy the above formula.  I'm going to claim it's **Θ(n<sup>6</sup>)**, and will try to justify this with the rest of my answer.

First, note that the value certainly isn't any more than O(n<sup>6</sup>).  All of a, b, c, d, e, and f range between 0 and n-1, so there's at most n different values for each.  Therefore, the maximum possible number of values they can have is n<sup>6</sup>.  This is not a tight bound, but it's certainly an upper bound.  That gives us that the runtime is at most O(n<sup>6</sup>).

If we want to get a tighter bound, we have to work harder.  To do this, I'm going to use the following fact:

> 1<sup>k</sup> + 2<sup>k</sup> + 3<sup>k</sup> + ... + n<sup>k</sup> = Θ(n<sup>k</sup>)

This is the sum of a geometric series, which is where it comes from.

This means that

```
sum(f from 0 to n-1)
   sum (e from 0 to f)
      sum (d from 0 to e)
          sum (c from 0 to d)
              sum (b from 0 to c)
                  sum (a from 0 to b)
                      1

=  sum(f from 0 to n-1)
     sum (e from 0 to f)
        sum (d from 0 to e)
            sum (c from 0 to d)
                sum (b from 0 to c)
                    Theta(b)

=  sum(f from 0 to n-1)
     sum (e from 0 to f)
        sum (d from 0 to e)
            sum (c from 0 to d)
                Theta(c^2)

=  sum(f from 0 to n-1)
     sum (e from 0 to f)
        sum (d from 0 to e)
            Theta(d^3)

=  sum(f from 0 to n-1)
     sum (e from 0 to f)
        Theta(e^4)

=  sum(f from 0 to n-1)
     Theta(f^5)

= Theta(n^6)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, I was playing around with the Stackexchange query engine, and landed here again. I have to take issue with your `1^k + 2^k ... = O(n^k)` etc... formula. `1 + 2 + ... + n-1 + n = O(n^2)`, and `1 != 2`. We did come to the same conclusion though, so I hope that part is right :).

Comment: The formula isn't geometric, as there's not a constant ratio between successive terms. [This Rutgers Math article](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~erowland/sumsofpowers-project.html) seems to indicate that the series is actually O(n^(k + 1))

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **Θ(n<sup>6</sup>)**. I wrote a program to simulate the inner loop and record how many times a series of `n` executions occurs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int arrLength = 20;
    int[] arr = new int[arrLength];

    for (int f = 0; f < arrLength; f++)
    {
        for (int e = 0; e <= f; e++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d <= e; d++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c <= d; c++)
                {
                    for (int b = 0; b <= c; b++)
                    {
                        //for (int a = 0; a <= b; a++)
                        arr[b] = arr[b] + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} execution: {1} time(s).", i + 1, arr[i]));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} execution: {1} time(s).", i + 1, arr[i]));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Running this with an arrLength of 1 gives:

```
1 execution: 1 time(s).
```

Running this with an arrLength of 2 gives:

```
1 execution: 5 time(s).
2 execution: 1 time(s).
```

Running this with an arrLength of 3 gives:

```
1 execution: 15 time(s).
2 execution: 5 time(s).
3 execution: 1 time(s).
```

As it turns out, the execution times always follow the same equation. At arrLength of 20, we get:

```
1 execution: 8855 time(s).
2 execution: 7315 time(s).
3 execution: 5985 time(s).
4 execution: 4845 time(s).
5 execution: 3876 time(s).
6 execution: 3060 time(s).
7 execution: 2380 time(s).
8 execution: 1820 time(s).
9 execution: 1365 time(s).
10 execution: 1001 time(s).
11 execution: 715 time(s).
12 execution: 495 time(s).
13 execution: 330 time(s).
14 execution: 210 time(s).
15 execution: 126 time(s).
16 execution: 70 time(s).
17 execution: 35 time(s).
18 execution: 15 time(s).
19 execution: 5 time(s).
20 execution: 1 time(s).
```

Plugging this into the awesome [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/), we get the *Binomial coefficient binomial(n,4)*, which is this (the sequence starts at an offset of 4):

[image]

```
binomial(n,4)
n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)/24
0 = 0
1 = 0
2 = 0
3 = 0
4 = 1
5 = 5
6 = 15
7 = 35
...
```

If we look at the execution patterns output by my program above, we can rewrite it using a summation and this binomial sequence. For each integer i between 1 and n inclusive, we have the `(n - i + 4)th` number in the `binomial(n,4)` sequence, then multiplied by `i`, as the total number of executions. This is expressed as the following:

[image: First Equation]

Substituting `j = n - i + 1`, and realizing that `j` goes from n downto 1, we can rewrite this equation as:

[image]

Relying on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to figure out this equation, I plugged in `sum (n-j+1)(j+3)(j+2)(j+1)*j/24, j = 1 to n`, and it came up with:

[image]

This is very obviously Θ(n<sup>6</sup>), so that is our answer.

The final equation is actually `binomial(n,6)`, so for m loops, the number of executions of the innermost loop is probably `binomial(n,m)`. For a given number of m loops, we have:

[image]